# How to create Airbnb iOS App Explore tab?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

[image: airbnb full]
[image: airbnb full]

---

I'm trying to create a feed page similar as the screenshots from Airbnb app. I started off with a `UITableViewController` and added animation to the header on scroll; the header is the turquoise-color area there.

Now I want to add those page tabs ("For You", "Homes", "Experiences", and "Places") and confused how I should structure my views. FYI each of the tab is a `tableView`. Right now my structure without page tabs is:

1. `UITabBarController`
2. `UIViewController` (contains `UIView` header, `UITableView` content)

There are few options that I can think of:

1. Each of the page tab is a `UITableViewDataSource`, so clicking a tab is just a change of `dataSource` and `reloadData()`
2. `UIViewController` will contain a `UIScrollView` contentView, so clicking a tab is `addSubView` to the contentView and `addChildViewController` to the controller

Based on my research, Option #2 is not recommended as it puts tableView inside a scrollView. But Option #1 requires all tableView to have the same cellID for dequeue? Sounds hardcode. Please advise me the best practice for this scenario! Thanks.

Comment: i would go for first option but try to use collection View instead of tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should consider use of **Container Views** in case you describe. In this way you going to have seperate views for each case that you have describe.

Example for you:

**In storyboard**:

[image]

And hear is code that switch views.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var containerViewA: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerViewB: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func showComponent(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.containerViewA.alpha = 1
                self.containerViewB.alpha = 0
            })
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.containerViewA.alpha = 0
                self.containerViewB.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! well I've also thought of this, but how do I link the animation on the header? because the header should expand and shrink as I scroll the tableView inside the containerView; which leads to my option #2 using `UIScrollView`

Comment: Use delegates method to trigger you're header from container views .

Comment: hmm let me give it a shot first :)

Comment: @yonasstephen I'm having trouble with the resizable headerview for this exact AirBnB explore screen. I tried using a headerView but the tableview will then have the ability to scroll over the headerview if the user scrolls upwards. I've tried adjusting the top constraint of the tableview but then you cannot scroll if the top constraint is being changed within `scrollViewDidScroll`. I've tried using a plain UIView (not headerView) with tableview and then creating a massive headerview and massive footerview and capping tableview offset, but then tableview bounce is lost. Any tips?

Comment: @program234 well my solution uses a plain `UIView` as the header and still able to have the tableView bounce. Have you seen this tutorial before? https://michiganlabs.com/ios/development/2016/05/31/ios-animating-uitableview-header/ hopefully it helps

Comment: @program234 I uploaded my project here: https://github.com/yonasstephen/swift-of-airbnb in case you're interested to see the full implementation